# How to evaluate this series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^{{1}/{n}}}{n^2}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

How to evaluate this series$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^{{1}/{n}}}{n^2}$$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}^+$ or $x \in \mathbb{C}$

Comment: This is a tough question, what can you say about it ?

Comment: Why would anybody evaluate that?

Comment: Plotting it, it looks very close to a linear function.

Comment: what is precisely $x^{1/n}$ if $x$ is not a positive real?; for $x>0, x^{1/n} = e^{\frac{ \log x}{n}}$ so the series can be approximated

Comment: @Conrad Choose one single value leaf of the multivalued function $x \mapsto x^{1/n}$

Comment: I'm pessimistic about a closed form representation for this, but at least for $x\in \Bbb{R}_+$ I found that the sum is very close to $1.007x+0.6.$ [Here's a graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fkjuanncve).

Comment: I'm voting leave open but I am *very skeptical* a nice representation exists. OP should specify where this came from and why they think a closed-form is possible.